# PHP filter_var: FILTER_VALIDATE_URL include more cases

Tags: php, filter, spam-prevention

It only validates urls that are of the format: http://www.example.com

How do I also validate partial urls, such as: www.example.com, example.com, or blah/example.php, etc...

(I need to do this to filter out posts/comments that only contain a url)

Comment: The problem is that your partial URLs are no URLs at all. They are identifiers that rely on address bar behaviour, or detection magic (which is what you need).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matching loosely formed urls using regex and php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3934170/matching-loosely-formed-urls-using-regex-and-php) (Use the one from NikiC with `^` and `$` anchors) - Or browse through these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=php%20regex%20detect%20www.example.com%20urls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe HTML has some new input types that do this for you, I dont know if it does it the way you want but here have a look!
http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_form_input_types.asp